# Show random div with delay on loop

Tags: javascript, html

I have got so far with this but as I am relatively new to JavaScript have soon become quite stuck. I would like to randomly show a div that fades in, if visible for 5 seconds and then fades out. There should then be a 10 second delay before the next random div appears. Ideally no two divs should show back to back.

If possible could the delay between showing one then another be random between 10-20 seconds?

```js
$(".demoBooked").fadeIn(2000).delay(5000).fadeOut(1000);
```

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

.demoBooked {
  background: GOLD;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="demoBooked">Demo 01</p>
<p class="demoBooked">Demo 02</p>
<p class="demoBooked">Demo 03</p>
<p class="demoBooked">Demo 04</p>
<p class="demoBooked">Demo 05</p>
<p class="demoBooked">Demo 06</p>
<p class="demoBooked">Demo 07</p>
<p class="demoBooked">Demo 08</p>
<p class="demoBooked">Demo 09</p>
<p class="demoBooked">Demo 10</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a [shuffle algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array) against the array with a queue. When the item is done fading out, you take the next item off the list. When you runout, shuffle the array again or just stop it.

```js
function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length,
    temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}

var queue = [];

function setUp() {
  var elems = $(".demoBooked").get();
  queue = shuffle(elems);
  showNext();
}

function showNext() {
  var elem = queue.pop();
  if (elem) {
    $(elem)
      .fadeIn(2000)
      .delay(5000)
      .fadeOut(1000, showNext);
  } else {
    setUp();
  }
}

setUp();
```

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

.demoBooked {
  background: GOLD;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="demoBooked">Demo 01</p>
<p class="demoBooked">Demo 02</p>
<p class="demoBooked">Demo 03</p>
<p class="demoBooked">Demo 04</p>
<p class="demoBooked">Demo 05</p>
<p class="demoBooked">Demo 06</p>
<p class="demoBooked">Demo 07</p>
<p class="demoBooked">Demo 08</p>
<p class="demoBooked">Demo 09</p>
<p class="demoBooked">Demo 10</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Is there a way to add a delay between showing a new one? At the moment the next div shows instantly, can we wait 10 seconds before showing another?

Comment: So add a timeout `.fadeOut(1000, function(){ setTimeout(showNext,2000); });`

Answer (score 0):

from what I get, you want a random <p> every time? here

```
setInterval(() => {
 // generate a random number
 var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

 // show the random .demoBooked
 $(document.querySelectorAll('.demoBooked')[randomNum]).fadeIn(2000).delay(5000).fadeOut(1000);
}, 10000);
```

(you just need JS for this)

Comment: Kind of, so the showing of the div is correct, however, I would like them to fade in/out but also have a 10 second delay between each one showing.

For example:

Page Loads
Div fades in & shows for 5 seconds, then fades out
10 second delay

process repeats

Answer (score 0):

And this is my solution using `setInterval()`.

```js
function show() {
let p_length = $('.demoBooked').length;
let p_random = Math.floor(Math.random() * p_length);
$('.demoBooked').eq(p_random).fadeIn(2000).delay(5000).fadeOut(1000);
}

show();
setInterval(show, 10000);
```

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

.demoBooked {
  background: GOLD;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="demoBooked">Demo 01</p>
<p class="demoBooked">Demo 02</p>
<p class="demoBooked">Demo 03</p>
<p class="demoBooked">Demo 04</p>
<p class="demoBooked">Demo 05</p>
<p class="demoBooked">Demo 06</p>
<p class="demoBooked">Demo 07</p>
<p class="demoBooked">Demo 08</p>
<p class="demoBooked">Demo 09</p>
<p class="demoBooked">Demo 10</p>
```